# IdIOHandlerThrottle missing in indy10

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I can't find the IdIOHandlerThrottle component in Indy10.
Is it removed or replaced ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is replaced by `TIdInterceptThrottler`.